# Publish gradle android library on server

Tags: java, android, github, gradle, dependency-management

I'm trying to provide dependencies with `Gradle` to my team, both for internal uses and for third parties. This is mostly for Android and Java, but a general answer is better.

All the information I have found is more on adding Gradle dependencies to projects, but not on how to setup these dependencies to be able to be provided.

I know already how to hardlink to a gradle project with:

```
project(':some-lib').projectDir = new File('SomeDirectoryAddress')
```

But I would want to get to a point where I can add the dependency without having to hardcode its address as with other libraries provided by third parties:

```
compile 'com.somecompany.somelibrary:somelibrary-android:1.5.0'
```

Could you guide me on where to look implement this kind of service?

Is it possible to serve the projects from GitHub/Git repositories? What should I do in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are just 2 standard servers used for host the libraries for Android such as jcenter and Maven Central

Need to follow following steps:

1. Generate JavaDoc and source JARs
2. Setup BinTray upload
3. Register on [BinTray.com](https://bintray.com/)
4. Add details to local.properties file

Details steps are mentioned in the following links

https://www.virag.si/2015/01/publishing-gradle-android-library-to-jcenter/

http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en

Answer (score 2):

Just as an addition to the information already posted. I haven't used it, but I've found JitPack, a tool that makes pulling dependencies from GitHub possible.

https://jitpack.io/